# polymer - two vaadin-grids in separate paper-tabs - populating on select

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, vaadin-grid

my first post and my first polymer app so I appreciate your patience. I'm using paper-tabs and iron-pages to enclose two vaadin-grids that populate via the same iron-ajax set-up - slightly different parameters. The code I have is as follows:

```
<ajax-api 
    data="{{apidata}}" 
    sortby="{{sortColumn}}"
    gender="{{gen}}"
    cat="{{category}}"
    weapon="{{weap}}">    
</ajax-api>
  <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" sticky>
    <paper-tab>Mens {{category}} {{weap}}</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab>Womens {{category}} {{weap}}</paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
     <iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">

      <div>
        <vaadin-grid id="mens" items="[[apidata.mens]]" visible-rows = 15 >
          <table>
          <colgroup>
          <col name="rank" />
          .
          .
          .           
          <col name="cat" hidable="" hidden="" />
          </colgroup>
          </table>
        </vaadin-grid>
      </div> 

      <div>
        <vaadin-grid id="womens" items="[[apidata.womens]]" visible-rows = 15>
          <table>
          <colgroup>
          <col name="rank" />
          .
          .
          .           
          <col name="cat" hidable="" hidden="" />
          </colgroup>
          </table>
        </vaadin-grid>
      </div>
```

Currently as you can probably see I'm using one ajax call to populate both mens and womens data at the same time - doesnt seem too efficient and is a pain when I start sorting it. The element ajax-api has two way binding that forms the parameters of an iron-ajax call and returns the data. I'd like to have the data load separately on selection of the tab. To complicate matters I'm also using  the grid column renderer to re-style some of the data. I'm figuring having selection change the bound gender property will trigger my ajax element so my question is how do I do that and how can I then ensure my grid column renderer function is referencing the correct grid.

EDIT:
I thought maybe I should add the content of the Polymer function to see if that helps someone frame a response.

```
<script>

Polymer({

  is: 'my-rankings1',

   properties: {
      sortColumn: { 
         type: String,
         value: "points",
       },
      sortDirection: String,
      sortProperty: String
    },

   ready: function() {
      var grid = this.$.mens;
      this.selected = 0;
      grid.addEventListener('sort-order-changed', function() {
        if (grid.size > 0) {
          grid.scrollToStart();
          var sortOrder = grid.sortOrder[0];
          this.sortColumn = grid.columns[sortOrder.column].name;
          alert(this.sortColumn);
          grid.refreshItems();
        }
      }.bind(this));


      grid.then(function() {

        // Add a renderer for the index column
        grid.columns[0].renderer = function(cell) {
         cell.element.innerHTML = cell.row.index +1;
        };

        grid.columns[6].renderer = function(cell) {
          if (cell.data < 0){
            cell.element.innerHTML =  Math.abs(cell.data) + '<iron-icon icon="arrow-downward" style="color: red"/>';

          }
          else if (cell.data > 0) {
            cell.element.innerHTML = cell.data + '<iron-icon icon="arrow-upward" style="color: green"/>';

          }
          else {cell.element.innerHTML = '<iron-icon icon="settings-ethernet" style="color: #ffcc00"/>';}

        };

    });
    },


  });
```